# SQL Server 2016 AlwaysOn Connection String

Tags: .net, connection-string, sql-server-2016

I seem to be having problem with connection a SQL Server 2016 with AlwaysOn feature using the user credentials. Our DBA created a contained database user. In SSMS, I use the Connection properties and then provide database name in "Connect to database" and in login tab, I provide user name and password and it works.

But when I use the same thing in .Net Framework Data Provider, it fails to connect.

Here is my connection string.

```
Data Source=ProdSQL2016; Initial Catalog=CustomerPortal;
    Integrated security=false;User Id=portal_user;Password=gfhSRfv&ehjds96;
```

Comment: Need more info on your setup.  Are you running the SQL server on the same PC you are developing on?

Comment: No.. It is running on different server. That is why I mentioned the Data Source in connection string

Comment: What exception do you receive when you try and connect?

Comment: it throws the login failure

Comment: There are a million ways a login can fail, I can't help you unless you can narrow it down. I am assuming you are using `System.Data.SqlClient` which throws a `SqlException` on error.  Post the error message from the exception.

Comment: what kind connection string is this ? Sql '16 conn string looks like this https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2016/

Comment: I don't think connectonstrings.com has solution to my problem. To use the Contained database user, we ended up creating an AD user and then provide the user with a required permissions